# TypeScript Distributive Conditional Types - additional type parameter constraints

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand Conditional Types introduced in TypeScript 2.8 and reading the below official documentation.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

In Distributive conditional types, there is an example

```
type BoxedValue<T> = { value: T };
type BoxedArray<T> = { array: T[] };
type Boxed<T> = T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>;

type T20 = Boxed<string>;  // BoxedValue<string>;
type T21 = Boxed<number[]>;  // BoxedArray<number>;
type T22 = Boxed<string | number[]>;  // BoxedValue<string> | BoxedArray<number>;
```

In the above example, i didn't understand the meaning of
`T[number]`
in
`BoxedArray<T[number]>`

Is it referring to the first element of the Array passed or what is happening here?

Can someone please help me explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's a "[lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types)" or "indexed access type".  `A[B]` is the type of the value you get when indexing into an object of type `A` with a key of type `B`.  So `T[number]` is what you get when you index into an object of type `T` with a numeric key.  Note that such a type will only compile if `T` is known to have a [numeric index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)... for example, if `T` is an array type, then `T[number]` is the type of the elements of the array.

Thus, `T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>` means "for each union member of `T`:  if it is an array type, produce a `BoxedArray` of its element type; otherwise, produce a `BoxedValue` of it, and join them all up in a single union", as the examples show.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That's (another) use of [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types). Basically think of `T[number]` as the type of any element accessible by any numeric index.

For a uniform array (every element has the same type) this is the same as doing `T[0]` which returns the type of the first element.

---

However this is not always the case. That's because TypeScript also has the concept of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

> Tuple types allow you to express an array with a fixed number of elements whose types are known, but need not be the same.

Let's say we have this tuple:

```js
type Tuple = [string, number, string];
```

The first element and the last will be of type `string`, but the second one is a `number`. Using a lookup type we can access the different indices:

```js
Tuple[0] // -> string
Tuple[1] // -> number
Tuple[2] // -> string
```

So if we use `number` in the lookup type we don't get the type of one single element, but a union of all possible types:

```js
Tuple[number] // -> string | number
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. It's very helpful.